# mysql query with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Suppose `business_type_master` and `contact_master`. The primary key of `business_type_master` is entered in `contact_master` table in comma separated value like `2,3,4`.

Now I am going to join those tables and using `GROUP_CONCAT`. But it does not return the desired output. My output will be like this

- `business_type_id` ==> `2,3,4`
- `business_name`  ==> `A,B,C`

But my output is like below

- `business_type_id` ==> `2,3,4`
- `business_name` ==> `A`

My query is

```
SELECT cm.contact_id, cm.full_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(cm.business_id) AS business_type_id,             
  GROUP_CONCAT(btm.business_type_name) AS business_type_name 
FROM contact_master AS cm           
JOIN business_type_master AS btm ON cm.business_id = btm.business_type_id 
GROUP BY cm.contact_id
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Redesign your tables,primary key and comma separated values grates on my brain.

Comment: primary key with comma separated values gives me problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your data is stored (including sample data) and what the output should look like (all fields)?  Ideally, load up a sqlfiddle.com to share your schema and sample data

Comment: A field containing the key fields to another table in a comma separated list is likely to be a nightmare to maintain, and slow to process. However not sure this is what you are doing as there doesn't appear to be any attempt to split up the business_type_id to check if one of the values it contains is the business_id